# How "expensive" is it to call Fortran from C++?

Tags: c++, fortran, g++, gfortran

I'm writting a program in C++ that calls some functions I had written in Fortran. I was going to test a very basic example in which I call a function called toRadians from the C++ code:

```
real function toRadian(degree)
  implicit none

  real, intent(in) :: degree
  real :: radians

  radians = (degree*PI)/180
  return
end function toRadian
```

And so I wonder, is this "worth it"? When I finish the whole thing that function will be called within Fortran where the bulk of the computations will be done, but doing this basic example got me thinking about if, for a simple computation like this, is calling the Fortran function more expensive than just having that function in C++?

Sorry for my ignorance I'm not very sure about how the linking between these compiled codes works. (I'm also very new with Fortran so if you want to make any remark about the previous function please go ahead).

Thanks for your time and have a nice day.

Comment: For a simple function like that it's not worth the hassle. Why don't you just write your toRadion function in C?

Comment: For a function like this this might be serious overkill. However, for hardcore mathematical stuff (matrix multiplications, etc) this might pay off. But even there, I would recommend to use plain C libraries like LAPACK or else.
In general, if you call things from one programming language in another, you can get complications in memory management (well, not here, but okay), and runtime overhead.

Comment: @ThomasLang LAPACK is plain C?

Comment: Nope, that's pure Fortran, CLAPACK is not standard (only CBLAS is AFAIK). You need custom C wrappers on top of the Fortran library.

Comment: @VladimirF Sorry, my bad, it is really Fortran. Well, then you might want to call it, for heavy stuff it usually pays off. Be aware that there are other, very good libraries though written in C/C++, e.g. Armadillo, Eigen, LAPACK++ etc.

Comment: Usually calling a C++ or a Fortran function results in more or less the same call instruction in assembly. I can imagine a situation where that matters though: if the callee is short and executed often, C++ has a standard way to "inline" calls (so there is no call instruction anymore, which is faster), while the Fortran standard does not have such a thing. This can be achieved by other means: command-line option, compiler directive (see `!DIR$ INLINE` in IVF), and more generally through IPO optimization. It might also be more difficult for the compiler to optimize away cross-language calls.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut I do not thing there is any real or seriously perceived lack of the `inline` keyword in Fortran. First, the compilers can normally manage on their own quite well and second, Fortran has internal functions and statement functions which are extremely likely to be inlined.

Answer (score 2):

Calling a Fortran function is as cheap as calling another C++ function. Usually.

The problem is the compatibility between the two languages. The best way to start this in Fortran is to use `iso_c_binding` so that the function has a C calling convention.

Then the other issue is that both languages require their own runtime libraries, and there are no linker flag to use both. So the usual practice is to create a shared library for the Fortran code and link it against the C++ application (and vice-versa when it's calling C++ from Fortran).

Comment: I am confused by "there is no linker flag to use both". What is wrong with "g++ -lgfortran" and "gfortran -lstdc++"?

Comment: There are sometimes other libraries that you need to link against. Depends on the compiler, but there is no proper portable way of linking both runtimes.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher The way of calling the linker (or even the existence of a linker) is not described by the Fortran standard, so it can't be "portable" anyway. See section 1#4 of the standard: *"This document does not specify the mechanism by which programs are transformed for use on computing systems."* I suspect the situation is similar with the C++ standard.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Exactly. That's why only one "language" can be linked in a portable way.

Comment: You don't get the point. It's not even possible to link *one* language portably. This is not part of the standard. We don't even know there *is* a linker (as far as the standard is concerned, a Fortran program could be interpreted). And you are probably aware that linkers vary deeply with platform and OS.

Comment: Well, the compilers do provide you this tool, you just use the driver directly so that it sets the runtime libraries properly. Didn't know that Fortran doesn't this as part of the standard?